# How to load tables values into a datagridview by code and also edit the same using rowheader click event?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table called customer which has values already stored directly through SQL.However i would like to load it into the form containing a datagrid view.I want to dynamically bind it using code and also want to edit the values on a single on initiating the rowheader click event.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start reading ..

Maybe from here:
http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/5-working-with-data